# Deny ssh access to user but allow keyless ssh on some servers

Tags: ssh, redhat, sudo

Redhat 4/5:

Ok so here's the deal.  I need to lock down my servers and only allow users to log in via their ldap account. There's an application account that everyone uses, but I would rather have them use their LDAP account and then sudo over to the app user. I got that part, however, there are components with our app that requires the app user to have keyless ssh.  Wouldn't make sense to allow some users direct logon w/ the app user while others require LDAP.

In my sshd_config file I would set

```
DenyUser appuser
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set `DenyUsers appuser` then `appuser` can't log in, using keys or otherwise: Their login will be denied.

What you probably want to do is lock out `appuser`'s password and give that user a new SSH key that nobody has access to - Now nobody can log in as appuser unless they have the new SSH key, which would only be given to the components that need passwordless SSH access.  Everyone else can log in with their LDAP account and sudo to do whatever they need to do, which it sounds like you already have working.

Comment: Oh man, why didnt I think of that. I'll just set appuser's password to blank or something. PAM should deny access by default due to no password (I think).